# Create a Class to be used on controllers

Tags: javascript, sails.js, es6-class

I want to create a `Class` and make it available on my controllers. I don't want to use helpers in this particular case because I'm planning to create an npm package later with this code. I don't want to create a package now, because I don't want my code to be public.

I've tried adding this code inside a file in the hooks folder:

```
console.log('Hook executed!');

module.exports = class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Object created!');
    }
}
```

When I lift the app I see that the hook it's being loaded:

> info: Starting app...
>
> Hook executed!

Then in a random controller I'm adding:

```
const test = new Test();
```

And when I execute the controller:

> ReferenceError: Test is not defined

**Update: According to [the documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/hook-specification) hooks are defined in a different way. So maybe using hooks is not the best approach. Any ideas on how to make a Class available on the controllers *with or without* using hooks?**

Comment: Provided the Test class is defined in a file named Test.js right under the hook folder. Did you `import Test from 'path_to_hooks/hooks/Test.js` in your controller?

Comment: "in a random controller": would you happen to be in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020113/exporting-classes-with-node-js#18020211)?

Comment: @remix23 I'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` if I put that code inside a controller.

Comment: @StockOverflaw I've tried requiring the file in my bootstrap.js file and I had the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, researching a bit more about Sails *hooks* I found that they have a special syntax so that's not what I wanted. Also, as I've already said, I didn't want a controller or a helper.

So, since there's no default way in Sails to create a package without actually creating it and including it to the project dependencies, I took a different approach. It's not very elegant, but it solves this particular case. I've simply placed my `Test.js` file inside the `api` folder, and included it in my controller like this:

```
const Test = require(__dirname + '/../../test');
let test = new Test();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your files should be like these files shown bellow:

myClass.js

```
'use strict';
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'test';
  }
}
module.exports = Test;
```

The other file which you want to use this class should look like this:

index.js

```
const Test = require('./myClass');
let a = new Test();
console.log(a.name);
```

After that when you run index.js file, you will see 'test' in your console.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that hooks are loaded in the `sails.hooks` object and to call a specific hook you use `sails.hooks[<hook-name>]`

I think you want to use something like this to use your hook `sails.hooks.Test`

More about it https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/using-hooks

Comment: Both `sails.hooks.Test` and `sails.hooks.custom.Test` are `undefined`.